# Android browser does support indexed database?

Tags: android, html, cordova, indexeddb

I wrote an android application with phonegap. I would like to use indexedDB, but I always got an exception. NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3:264

when I initialize indexedDB I do not get an error:

```
//todo csinálni kell inicializált eventet

// In the following line, you should include the prefixes of implementations you want to test.
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
// DON'T use "var indexedDB = ..." if you're not in a function.
// Moreover, you may need references to some window.IDB* objects:
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;
// (Mozilla has never prefixed these objects, so we don't need window.mozIDB*)

if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Such and such feature will not be available.");
}
```

and when I log the indexedDB I get `[object IDBDatabase]`.

I get the error at this line: `var trans = db.transaction([index], "readwrite");`

My code works on at the desktop browser on the PC, it just does not work on the tablet. I have tested on Chrome and Firefox browser on my PC.

How can I solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, Android 4.1 (and above) have IndexedDB in both web client and stock browser. The implementation is buggy, incomplete and outdated though.

Instead of "readwrite", use old style `window.webkitIDBTransaction.READ_WRITE`.